# PDO INSERT statement not working inside counter loop

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, pdo

Can anyone let me know why this PDO Statement won't work inside the for loop? I'm trying to add one to the position for each new entry into the database. for some reason this is breaking. Any ideas on why?

**Edit**

Please ignore the next position, etc. For other reasons the `gp_position` can not be `AUTO_INCREMENT` and next position won't always start at 1. Please focus on why this PDO Statement won't work inside the loop.

```
    $nextPosition = 1;
    $imgID = 1;
    $indb_gridID = 1;
    $timesToRepeat = 33;
    $indb_mem_id  = ($this->user->is_logged_in()) ? $this->user->info['id'] : 1;
    for($i=1; $i<=$timesToRepeat; $i++) {

        // now add the image to the grid positions
        $stmt = dbpdo::$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO grid_positions SET
                                       gp_mem_id   = :memID,
                                       gp_g_id     = :gridID,
                                       gp_img_id   = :imgID,
                                       gp_position = :position");
        $stmt->bindParam(':memID', $indb_mem_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':gridID', $indb_gridID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':imgID', $imgID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':position', $nextPosition, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();

        $nextPosition++;    
    }
```

Comment: why do you even need your $nextPosition var, you can just use $i, it has the same value and increments on each loop.

Comment: Next position won't always start at 1... might start at 145769

Comment: bad logic. Your prepare your statement and bind your parameters **ONCE**. The only thing inside your loop should be `$stmt->execute(); $nextPosition++1;`. re-prepping and re-binding in a loop negates one of the primary purposes of using prepared statements.

Comment: but you're initialising it to 1 outside the loop so it will start at 1?

Comment: Why not have `gp_position` be an auto_increment column and then don't specify a value for it.

Comment: Marc B... It will know to use the new nextPosition value each time?

Comment: @ClintC. Yes. If you bind a parameter to a variable, the `execute()` call will use the value of that variable at the point in time where the `execute()` is called.

Answer (score 0):

Try this refactored code:

```
$nextPosition = 1;
$imgID = 1;
$indb_gridID = 1;
$timesToRepeat = 33;
$indb_mem_id  = ($this->user->is_logged_in()) ? $this->user->info['id'] : 1;

// prepare the statement once:
$stmt = dbpdo::$conn->prepare("INSERT INTO grid_positions SET
                                   gp_mem_id   = :memID,
                                   gp_g_id     = :gridID,
                                   gp_img_id   = :imgID,
                                   gp_position = :position");
$stmt->bindParam(':memID', $indb_mem_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':gridID', $indb_gridID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':imgID', $imgID, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindParam(':position', $nextPosition, PDO::PARAM_INT);

for($i=1; $i<=$timesToRepeat; $i++) {

    // exec statement with current values:
    $stmt->execute();

    $nextPosition++;    
}
```